# Allow function to ignore unsupported keyword arguments

Tags: julia, keyword-argument

Is there a nice way of allowing a function to ignore unsupported keyword arguments?

```
fopts = [:kw1]
opts = Dict(:kw1=>:symb1, :kw2=>:symb2)

function f(; kw1 = :symb)
    return kw1
end
```

`f(;opts...)` will throw a `METHOD ERROR`

I could wrap it in something like this, but then I still need to know which kwargs `f` will support?

```
function f2(fopts; kwargs)
    f(; Dict(key=>get(opts, key, 0) for key in fopts)...)
end
```

Am I missing a way around this. Not that fussed if there is a performance penalty as I imagine their may need to be some kind of look up. Is there a good way of interrogating what kwargs `f` accepts programatically?

Comment: You could define your function as `f(x; kwargs...) = (kwargs = Dict(kwargs); ...)` and just use the keywords your function should support and ignore the rest.

Comment: if i understood properly, you might look for something like this: `fopts=methods(methods(f).mt.kwsorter).mt.defs.func.lambda_template.slotnames`. i guess there must be a clean way to do this.

Comment: Indeed I feel like there are other usecases for a `getkwargs` function...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
function g(; kw1 = :a, kw2 = :b, _whatever...)
    return (kw1, kw2)
end
```

Now it works like this:

```
julia> g()
(:a,:b)

julia> g(kw1 = :c)
(:c,:b)

julia> g(kw2 = :d)
(:a,:d)

julia> g(kw2 = :e, kw1 = :f, kw3 = :boo)
(:f,:e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on both @tim & @Gnimuc's comments one could define these two functions:

```
getkwargs(f) = methods(methods(f).mt.kwsorter).mt.defs.func.lambda_template.slotnames[4:end-4]

usesupportedkwargs2(f::Function, args...; kwargs...) = f(args...; Dict(key=>get(Dict(kwargs),key,0) for key in getkwargs(f))...)
```

But maybe there is a better way